# Perl Parser using Hash

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I am new to perl and not a very good with data structures. I have been working on a text parser to extract information from a text file and store it in a database. The regular patterns are now ok but,i just noticed that the key i used for my hash **"Time"** is not unique since there are multiple updates(in the text file) that could happen at the same time. What the hash does is create duplicates which are unacceptable for my purpose. So i was thinking to add a another key maybe a unique counter but i don't know how to get about it. So i tried to add a another key **"{$recordcnt}"** as counter you will see it appended on all hash statements.I deleted the counter increment statements(maybe i didn't implement correctly)

Also, if you look at the print statement block(last section) of my code, i am trying to print get an array **(@nodes_and_index)** value that contains two columns nodes and index, print it and display them differently. However it doesn't print the desired results. Was testing assuming i wanted to enter the data into the database separately.

So, did i put the **"{$recordcnt}"** in the wrong places, if so. How do i make each entry **unique in the hash** with time ? Thanks for reading.

**This is an example of my data:**

```
TIME: 11/01/13 14:30:24
FROM: 10.255.9.4 AS172193
TO: 10.255.9.10 AS676767
ASPATH: 172193 19601 14835 1286 577 4097 2841 14735 9486 573 10633 4488
NEXT_HOP: 10.255.9.126
ANNOUNCE
  10.44.193.0/24

TIME: 11/01/13 14:30:24
FROM: 10.255.9.4 AS172193
TO: 10.255.9.10 AS676767
ASPATH: 172193 19601 14835 4758 2379 10721 10787 7830 17777 4875 4488
NEXT_HOP: 10.255.9.126
ANNOUNCE
  10.44.193.0/24

TIME: 11/01/13 14:30:25
FROM: 10.255.9.4 AS172193
TO: 10.255.9.10 AS676767
ASPATH: 172193 19601 14835 4758 2379 10721 10787 7830 17777 16480 9486 573 10633 4488
NEXT_HOP: 10.255.9.126
ANNOUNCE
  10.44.193.0/24

TIME: 11/01/13 14:30:25
FROM: 10.255.9.4 AS172193
TO: 10.255.9.10 AS676767
ASPATH: 172193 19601 19602 3252 3665 2315 2379 10721 7311 12934 4875 4488
NEXT_HOP: 10.255.9.125
ANNOUNCE
  10.44.193.0/24

TIME: 11/01/13 14:30:34
FROM: 10.255.9.4 AS172193
TO: 10.255.9.10 AS676767
ASPATH: 172193 19601 19602 3252 3665 2315 2379 3725
NEXT_HOP: 10.255.9.125
ANNOUNCE
  10.44.193.0/24
```

**This is my full code :**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;
my $Dir = "/root/updates/processed/";
my $exit = 0;
my $recordcnt = 0 ;
opendir(DIRECTORY, $Dir) or die $!;

while (my $file = readdir(DIRECTORY)) { 

    unless ($file=~/\.hr$/){next;}


    my $file = $Dir."/".$file;
    print "$file\n";

    open (IN, $file) or die "error reading file: ", $file,"\n";

    my $record_id = "";
    #my $recordcnt = 0 ;
    my $type = "";
    my $peer_ip = "";
    my $peer_as = "";
    my $local_ip = "";
    my $local_as = "";
    my $next_hop = "";
    my @nodes_and_index = ();
    my @withdraw_prefix = ();
    my @announce_prefix = ();



    while (<IN>) {          

        #$exit++; last if ($exit==5);

        if (/^TIME/) {

            if ($type) {$hash{$record_id}{$recordcnt}{'type'} = $type;}
            if ($peer_ip) {$hash{$record_id}{$recordcnt}{'peer_ip'} = $peer_ip;}
            if ($peer_as) {$hash{$record_id}{$recordcnt}{'peer_as'} = $peer_as;}
            if ($local_ip) {$hash{$record_id}{$recordcnt}{'local_ip'} = $local_ip;}
            if ($local_as) {$hash{$record_id}{$recordcnt}{'local_as'} = $local_as;}
            if ($next_hop) {$hash{$record_id}{$recordcnt}{'next_hop'} = $next_hop;}

            if (@nodes_and_index) {push @{$hash{$record_id}{$recordcnt}{'nodes_and_index'}}, @nodes_and_index;}  
            if (@withdraw_prefix) {push @{$hash{$record_id}{$recordcnt}{'withdraw_prefix'}}, @withdraw_prefix;}
            if (@announce_prefix) {push @{$hash{$record_id}{$recordcnt}{'announce_prefix'}}, @announce_prefix;}

            $peer_as = "";
            $peer_ip = "";
            $type = "";
            $local_ip = "";
            $local_as = "";
            $next_hop = "";
            $record_id = "";
            $recordcnt = 0;
            @nodes_and_index = ();
            @withdraw_prefix = ();
            @announce_prefix = ();


            my @time = split '\s', $_;
            $record_id = $time[1]."_".$time[2]; 

        } elsif (/^FROM/) {
            my @from_tmp = split '\s', $_;
            $peer_ip = $from_tmp[1];
            $peer_as = $from_tmp[2];
            $peer_as =~ s/AS//;

        } elsif (/^TO/) {
            my @to_tmp = split '\s', $_;
            $local_ip = $to_tmp[1];
            $local_as = $to_tmp[2];
            $local_as =~ s/AS//;
            #print "$local_ip\n"; 

        } elsif (/^ASPATH/) {

            my @nodes_tmp = split '\s', $_;
                shift @nodes_tmp;       
            my $index = 0;

            foreach my $node (@nodes_tmp) {
                  $index++;
                  push @nodes_and_index, ($node , $index);
             }  

        }elsif (/^NEXT_HOP/) {

            my @next_hop_tmp = split '\s', $_;
            $next_hop = $next_hop_tmp[1];  

        }elsif (/^WITHDRAW/) {
            while (<IN>) {       
                     last if !/^ +/;     
                     @withdraw_prefix, $_ ;             
                 }


        }elsif (/^ANNOUNCE/) {
                while (<IN>) {        
                        last if !/^ +/;    
                push @announce_prefix, $_;

                 }  
            }


        if ($record_id) { # handle last result
            $hash{$record_id}{$recordcnt}{'peer_as'}    = $peer_as;
            $hash{$record_id}{$recordcnt}{'peer_ip'}    = $peer_ip;
            $hash{$record_id}{$recordcnt}{'local_as'}   = $local_as;
            $hash{$record_id}{$recordcnt}{'local_ip'}   = $local_ip;
            $hash{$record_id}{$recordcnt}{'next_hop'}   = $next_hop;

            push @{$hash{$record_id}{$recordcnt}{'nodes_and_index'}} ,@nodes_and_index;  
            push @{$hash{$record_id}{$recordcnt}{'withdraw_prefix'}} ,@withdraw_prefix;
            push @{$hash{$record_id}{$recordcnt}{'announce_prefix'}} ,@announce_prefix;

        }
    }
    close IN;
}  
my @arraystuff;
my @separated;
my @iindex=();
my @ppath=();
foreach (sort keys %hash) {

    print $_, "\n";
    print "\t $hash{$_}{$recordcnt}{'peer_ip'}\n";
    print "\t $hash{$_}{$recordcnt}{'peer_as'}\n";
    print "\t $hash{$_}{$recordcnt}{'local_ip'}\n";
    print "\t $hash{$_}{$recordcnt}{'local_as'}\n"; 
    print "\t $hash{$_}{$recordcnt}{'next_hop'}\n";

    @arraystuff = @{$hash{$_}{$recordcnt}{'nodes_and_index'}};
    foreach (@arraystuff) {
         @separated = split('\s', $_);
         push @iindex, $separated[1];
         push @ppath, $separated[0];
         print "\t index: @iindex";
         print "\t path: @ppath";
        }


    print "\t node index : @{$hash{$_}{$recordcnt}{'nodes_and_index'}}\n";    
    print "\t withdraw_prefix: @{$hash{$_}{$recordcnt}{'withdraw_prefix'}}\n"; 
    print "\t announce: @{$hash{$_}{$recordcnt}{'announce_prefix'}}\n"; 
}
```

## ==========================================================================================

New version advised by Foibs

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;


my @datasetarray;
my $Dir = "/root/updates\/processed/";
my $exit = 0;  

opendir(DIRECTORY, $Dir) or die $!;

while (my $file = readdir(DIRECTORY)) { 

    unless ($file=~/\.hr$/){next;}
    #unless ($file=~/\.txt$/){next;}

    my $file = $Dir."/".$file;
    print "$file\n";

    open (IN, $file) or die "error reading file: ", $file,"\n";

    my $record_id = "";
    my $type = "";
    my $peer_ip = "";
    my $peer_as = "";
    my $local_ip = "";
    my $local_as = "";
    my $next_hop = "";
    my @nodes_and_index = ();
    my @withdraw_prefix = ();
    my @announce_prefix = ();


    my $tmphash = {};

    while (<IN>) {          

        #$exit++; last if ($exit==5);

        if (/^TIME/) {


            if ($type) {$tmphash->{'type'} = $type;}
            if ($peer_ip) {$tmphash->{'peer_ip'} = $peer_ip;}
            if ($peer_as) {$tmphash->{'peer_as'} = $peer_as;}
            if ($local_ip) {$tmphash->{'local_ip'} = $local_ip;}
            if ($local_as) {$tmphash->{'local_as'} = $local_as;}
            if ($next_hop) {$tmphash->{'next_hop'} = $next_hop;}
               #if (@nodes_and_index) {push {$tmphash->{'nodes_and_index'}}, @nodes_and_index;}  
            #if (@withdraw_prefix) {push {$tmphash->{'withdraw_prefix'}}, @withdraw_prefix;}
            #if (@announce_prefix) {push {$tmphash->{'announce_prefix'}}, @announce_prefix;}

#The three commented lines above provide error, thus i don't know if i am implementing it the right way, since they are array and different from the others.

            $peer_as = "";
            $peer_ip = "";
            $type = "";
            $local_ip = "";
            $local_as = "";
            $next_hop = "";
            $record_id = "";
            @nodes_and_index = ();
            @withdraw_prefix = ();
            @announce_prefix = ();


            my @time = split '\s', $_;
            $record_id = $time[1]."_".$time[2];


        } elsif (/^TYPE/) {
            my @type_tmp = split '\s', $_;
            $type = $type_tmp[1];

        } elsif (/^FROM/) {
            my @from_tmp = split '\s', $_;
            $peer_ip = $from_tmp[1];
            $peer_as = $from_tmp[2];
            $peer_as =~ s/AS//;

        } elsif (/^TO/) {
            my @to_tmp = split '\s', $_;
            $local_ip = $to_tmp[1];
            $local_as = $to_tmp[2];
            $local_as =~ s/AS//;

        } elsif (/^ASPATH/) {

            my @nodes_tmp = split '\s', $_;
                shift @nodes_tmp;       
            my $index = 0;

            foreach my $node (@nodes_tmp) {
                    $index++;
            push @nodes_and_index, ($node , $index); 
             }  

        }elsif (/^NEXT_HOP/) {

            my @next_hop_tmp = split '\s', $_;
            $next_hop = $next_hop_tmp[1];  

        }elsif (/^WITHDRAW/) {
            while (<IN>) {       
                     last if !/^ +/;    
                     push @withdraw_prefix, $_ ;           

                 }


        }elsif (/^ANNOUNCE/) {

                 while (<IN>) {        
                     last if !/^ +/;    
                     push @announce_prefix, $_;

                 }  

            }


        if ($record_id) { # handle last result
            push @datasetarray, $tmphash;
            $tmphash = {};
        }
    }
    close IN; 
}  

foreach my $row (@datasetarray) {


    print $_, "\n";                       #Time doesn't get printed
    print "\t $row->{'peer_ip'}\n";       #OK
    print "\t $row->{'peer_as'}\n";       #OK
    print "\t $row->{'local_ip'}\n";      #OK
    print "\t $row->{'local_as'}\n";      #OK
    print "\t $row->{'next_hop'}\n";      #OK
#   print "\t $row->{'nodes_and_index'}\n"; # Are these guys ok ? since they are arrays
#   print "\t $row->{'withdraw_prefix'}\n"; # Are these guys ok ? since they are arrays
#   print "\t $row->{'announce_prefix'}\n"; # Are these guys ok ? since they are arrays


}
```

## ============================================================================

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest seems to be to put your `$recordcnt` in the key itself like this `$record_id = $recordcnt.'_'.$time[1]."_".$time[2];` and make sure that it never gets zeroed inside the loop (you have a line that does $recordcnt=0`, this is wrong). Also I didn't find any place where you actually increment the recordcnt.

---

However, it seems to me that you'd be much better off by using an array of hashes instead of a simple hash. The array will be ordered the same as your input file but you can use `sort` to sort it any way and you don't get messed up with strange counters and such. It's not too hard to rewrite it with an array.

First, create the array that will hold all your data in the beginning of your script (let's call it `@myarray`).

Before your loop starts, create a hash ref (reference to a hash, easier to handle) which will contain one object.

```
my $tmphash = {};
while (<IN>) {    
......
```

Now replace your `$hash{$record_id}{$recordcnt}` with just `$tmphash->`

(e.g.

`if ($peer_ip) {$hash{$record_id}{$recordcnt}{'peer_ip'} = $peer_ip;}`

will now be

`if ($peer_ip) {$tmphash->{'peer_ip'} = $peer_ip;}` and so on)

When you know that you have gathered the whole object in the `tmphash`, just push the `tmphash` in the array, reinitialize the tmphash and continue with the next object.

```
push @myarray, $tmphash;
$tmphash = {};
```

---

All done! Now all you need to do is loop through the array to print your data

```
foreach my $row (@myarray) {
  print "\t $row->{'peer_ip'}\n";
  #... and so on
```

---

**EDIT**

I took the liberty of fixing your script. There where small errors and a major logical error. I didn't delete anything of your code, but I commented out some lines and added some of my own. All lines that I changed or added are marked with a `#~#~` in the end of the line so you can easily track them and see the differences.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;


my @datasetarray;
my $Dir = "/root/updates/processed/";
my $exit = 0;  

opendir(DIRECTORY, $Dir) or die $!;

while (my $file = readdir(DIRECTORY)) { 

    unless ($file=~/\.hr$/){next;}
    #unless ($file=~/\.txt$/){next;}

    my $file = $Dir."/".$file;
    print "$file\n";

    open (IN, $file) or die "error reading file: ", $file,"\n";

    my $record_id = "";
    my $type = "";
    my $peer_ip = "";
    my $peer_as = "";
    my $local_ip = "";
    my $local_as = "";
    my $next_hop = "";
    my @nodes_and_index = ();
    my @withdraw_prefix = ();
    my @announce_prefix = ();


    my $tmphash = {};

    while (<IN>) {          

        #$exit++; last if ($exit==5);

        if (/^TIME/) {


            if ($type) {$tmphash->{'type'} = $type;}
            if ($peer_ip) {$tmphash->{'peer_ip'} = $peer_ip;}
            if ($peer_as) {$tmphash->{'peer_as'} = $peer_as;}
            if ($local_ip) {$tmphash->{'local_ip'} = $local_ip;}
            if ($local_as) {$tmphash->{'local_as'} = $local_as;}
            if ($next_hop) {$tmphash->{'next_hop'} = $next_hop;}
            if (@nodes_and_index) {push @{$tmphash->{'nodes_and_index'}}, @nodes_and_index;}  #~#~
            if (@withdraw_prefix) {push @{$tmphash->{'withdraw_prefix'}}, @withdraw_prefix;}  #~#~
            if (@announce_prefix) {push @{$tmphash->{'announce_prefix'}}, @announce_prefix;}  #~#~

            if ($record_id) {  #~#~
                $tmphash->{'time'} = $record_id; #~#~
                push @datasetarray, $tmphash;#~#~
                $tmphash = {};#~#~
            } #~#~
#The three commented lines above provide error, thus i don't know if i am implementing it the right way, since they are array and different from the others.

            $peer_as = "";
            $peer_ip = "";
            $type = "";
            $local_ip = "";
            $local_as = "";
            $next_hop = "";
            $record_id = "";
            @nodes_and_index = ();
            @withdraw_prefix = ();
            @announce_prefix = ();


            my @time = split '\s', $_;
            $record_id = $time[1]."_".$time[2];


        } elsif (/^TYPE/) {
            my @type_tmp = split '\s', $_;
            $type = $type_tmp[1];

        } elsif (/^FROM/) {
            my @from_tmp = split '\s', $_;
            $peer_ip = $from_tmp[1];
            $peer_as = $from_tmp[2];
            $peer_as =~ s/AS//;

        } elsif (/^TO/) {
            my @to_tmp = split '\s', $_;
            $local_ip = $to_tmp[1];
            $local_as = $to_tmp[2];
            $local_as =~ s/AS//;

        } elsif (/^ASPATH/) {

            my @nodes_tmp = split '\s', $_;
                shift @nodes_tmp;       
            my $index = 0;

            foreach my $node (@nodes_tmp) {
                    $index++;
            push @nodes_and_index, ($node , $index); 
             }  

        }elsif (/^NEXT_HOP/) {

            my @next_hop_tmp = split '\s', $_;
            $next_hop = $next_hop_tmp[1];  

        }elsif (/^WITHDRAW/) {
            while (<IN>) {       
                     last if !/^ +/;    
                     push @withdraw_prefix, $_ ;           

                 }


        }elsif (/^ANNOUNCE/) {

                 while (<IN>) {        
                     last if !/^ +/;    
                     push @announce_prefix, $_;

                 }  

            }


        #if ($record_id) { # handle last result #~#~
       #     push @datasetarray, $tmphash;#~#~
       #     $tmphash = {};#~#~
       # }#~#~
    }
    close IN; 

    #insert the last element of the file
    if ($type) {$tmphash->{'type'} = $type;} #~#~
    if ($peer_ip) {$tmphash->{'peer_ip'} = $peer_ip;} #~#~
    if ($peer_as) {$tmphash->{'peer_as'} = $peer_as;} #~#~
    if ($local_ip) {$tmphash->{'local_ip'} = $local_ip;} #~#~
    if ($local_as) {$tmphash->{'local_as'} = $local_as;} #~#~
    if ($next_hop) {$tmphash->{'next_hop'} = $next_hop;}  #~#~
    if (@nodes_and_index) {push @{$tmphash->{'nodes_and_index'}}, @nodes_and_index;}  #~#~
    if (@withdraw_prefix) {push @{$tmphash->{'withdraw_prefix'}}, @withdraw_prefix;}  #~#~
    if (@announce_prefix) {push @{$tmphash->{'announce_prefix'}}, @announce_prefix;}  #~#~

    if ($record_id) {  #~#~
        $tmphash->{'time'} = $record_id; #~#~
        push @datasetarray, $tmphash;#~#~
        $tmphash = {};#~#~
    } #~#~
}  

foreach my $row (@datasetarray) {


    #print $_, "\n";                       #Time doesn't get printed #~#~
    print "\t $row->{'time'}\n";       #~#~
    print "\t $row->{'peer_ip'}\n";       #OK
    print "\t $row->{'peer_as'}\n";       #OK
    print "\t $row->{'local_ip'}\n";      #OK
    print "\t $row->{'local_as'}\n";      #OK
    print "\t $row->{'next_hop'}\n";      #OK
#you can print array refs like this, just make a check that they are declared
   print "\t @{$row->{'nodes_and_index'}}\n" if ref $row->{'nodes_and_index'} eq 'ARRAY';#~#~
   print "\t @{$row->{'withdraw_prefix'}}\n" if ref $row->{'withdraw_prefix'} eq 'ARRAY';#~#~
   print "\t @{$row->{'withdraw_prefix'}}\n" if ref $row->{'withdraw_prefix'} eq 'ARRAY';#~#~


}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and giving me 2 options i really appreciate. I will like to try the first option by adding the recordcnt to the record_id as you suggested. Please where should i initialize and increment it ? Based on the results of this i will decide to go with option 2 which is better as you adviced:)

Comment: *now i have the counter working as expected. But I get duplicated values for example :*  
**ASPATH: 172193 1 19601 2 14835 3 4758 4 2379 5 172193 1 19601 2  14835 3 4758 4 2379 5 172193 1 19601 2 14835 3 4758 4 2379 5**  
*The results for that repeats 3 times i don't know why.*

Comment: Since you are using this `if (/^TIME/) {` block to distinguish new records, you should increment $recordcnt inside that `if` block. Right now you are setting it to 0 in that same if, which is wrong. You are already initializing it correctly outside all `while` loops.

Comment: Thanks i did that already. Now any idea why i have duplicates for ASPATH for example as i explained in my last comment ?

Comment: I can't tell for sure. There are a couple duplicates in the sample data you posted in the question, perhaps it is indeed duplicated data in your files? If not, please update your question with your newest code and the sample data that gives you these duplicates so we can test more

Comment: Dear @foibs i decided to go with the second option. I started to work on it but got stuck wrt to adding an array aswell in the hash. Please check my new code with comments in a moment.

Comment: Yeah, since you are now working with references, I forgot to say that you need to use the arrays as references too. Just add a `@` when you import the arrays to the hash like this `if (@nodes_and_index) {push @{$tmphash->{'nodes_and_index'}}, @nodes_and_index;}` and the same when you print them `print "\t @{$row->{'nodes_and_index'}}\n";` . Also, time does not get printed because it hasn't been passed into the tmphash. Just use an extra key for this `$tmphash->{'time'} = $record_id;` and `print $row->{'time'}` instead of `$_`;

Comment: Also there may be a logical error in the script. You initialize recordid and all vars correctly when you encounter a `TIME` line, but you push into the array for every loop (the record_id is defined right after the TIME line). I'll edit my answer with a fixed version of your script.

Comment: good afternoon and thanks for your prompt reply. I somehow have this error at the print statement :
''Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at CParray.pl line 143.'' The line 143, is where the print statements of the arrays are. Best regards

Comment: Hi, I just saw that and edited my answer. Have a look at my last comment and the edit :)

Comment: Thank you, i really appreciate (y). Will be waiting.

Comment: I am forever grateful ! Thank you for your time, knowledge and experience. It's working perfectly as expected.Your knowledge in perl and data structures is what i hope to archive in time.